# GetProperties of an EF object: need to ignore "RelationshipManager"

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to loop through all the properties of my EF entity code first object.  I only want the properties that I defined.  But when I do this, it includes a property 
"RelationshipManager" which I really don't want.

here is the object:

```
public class SchoolYear
{
        [Key]
        public virtual int SchoolYearId { get; set; }
        public virtual string SchoolYearName { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the code:

```
 public static string plistFromObject<T>(List<T> data)
 {
            string plist = "";

            plist = plist + "<array>\r\n";

            foreach (var item in data)
            {
                // I want to exclude "relationshipmanager"

                List<string> props = item.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly |     BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).Select(p => p.Name).ToList();

                plist = plist + "<dict>\r\n";

               foreach (var prop in props)
               {
                   var val = item.GetType().GetProperty(prop).GetValue(item, null).ToString();

                   plist = plist + "<key>" + prop + "</key>\r\n";
                   plist = plist + "<string>" + System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(val) + "</string>\r\n";
               }

            plist = plist + "</dict>\r\n";
        }

        return plist;
    }
```

the call

```
    [WebMethod]
    public string GetSchoolYears()
    {
        var db = new MyEntities();

        var results = (from i in db.SchoolYears
                       select i).ToList();


        return Library.Common.plistFromObject(results);
    }
```

Comment: Where's the rest of your object? Where is `RelationshipManager` defined? That will be a big clue.

Comment: Also, do yourself a big favor and don't build XML by using string manipulation. Use LINQ to XML instead. And if you insist on string manipulation, at least use a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: I don't know where relationshipmanager is defined. Is it part of EF? or a default property of object? THanks for the suggestion. I will switch to ling to XML or use string builder.

Comment: Where's the other "part" of your partial class? Look there. In particular, I want you to tell us the base class of your object. Also, which .NET version and EF version are you using?

Comment: [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=+RelationshipManager) suggests this may be the [`RelationshipManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.dataclasses.relationshipmanager.aspx) class.

Comment: Just out if curiosity, why don't you XML serialize the object instead of trying todo so yourself?

Comment: rand, can you point me to a good example? that would output plist tags? I normally use an xml serializer when I don't care about the tags it outputs.  I am sure you can specify the tag name in the serializer too. but it was simple enough to do it the way I did it.

Comment: john, I took out the partial class. it is just a class and it still have "RelationshipManager" returned as a prop.

Comment: john, how would I go about using linq to xml to get the output I want. I don't want the default xml of the object.  I need it in a plist format.

Comment: FYI, did you know you are using the ASMX technology? ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using Tony's answer: I was able to do it this way without having to filter out the EF dynamic property. This will get me the actual type of the object

```
 var xml = new XElement(
                        "array",
                        data.Select(d =>
                        new XElement("dict",ObjectContext.GetObjectType(d.GetType   ()).GetProperties(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)

                                                .Select(
                                                 p => new[] { 
                                                 new XElement("key",p.Name), 
                                                    new XElement("string", p.GetValue(d, null)) }
                                                        )
                                            )
                                 ));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try it like this:

```
var xml = new XElement(
        "array", 
        data.Select(d => 
           new XElement("dict",
            d.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
            .Where(p => p.Name != "RelationshipManager")
            .Select(
                p => new [] { 
                    new XElement("key",p.Name), 
                    new XElement("string", p.GetValue(d, null)) }
            )
        )
    ));
```

See [demo](http://dotnetfiddle.net/ttrypp).

The answer is that EF works not with your class exactly, but with special dynamic generated proxy classes, so even if you don't have such property, EF can add it. See more [details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592886.aspx).

Comment: This is a nice example of using linq to xml.. but really doesn't answer my question of where the "RelationshipManager" field is coming from.

Comment: @magic-c0d3r The answer is that EF works not with your class exactly, but with special dynamic generated proxy classes, so even if you don't have such property, EF can add it. See more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592886.aspx